# Battle Song Expertise - what bonus do I get?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, bard

The feat *Battle Song Expertise* states that

> "you gain a +1 feat bonus to attack rolls you make with any weapon or
>   wondrous item that has a property allowing you to use it as an
>   implement for your bard powers and bard paragon path powers." (Dragon 402)

I was going to pick up the *Arcane Implement Proficiency - Weapon* feat for my Skald to use my weapon for implement attacks and then improve the attack bonus with BSE, however, the wording on the feat makes it sound like the weapon NEEDS to be a Songblade or similar. Is this intended?
At the moment, the related *White Lotus Dueling Expertise* feat seems like a much better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Battle Song Expertise should work with weaplements.**

With the errata to the feat (see Patrick vD's answer), Battle Song Expertise now applies to "any weapon with which you are proficient". If you take Arcane Implement Proficiency for a kind of weapon, you will be proficient with it. It will also still be a weapon (even though you're using it as an implement). The feat does not limit its bonus to weapon powers, therefore you **do** gain the feat's bonus when using a weapon-as-implement.

Comment: It seems that the wording on the feat has been changed, so that it now works with any weapon with which you have proficiency. I guess? I don't have an Insider subscription, so that must be where everyone else is getting the alternative feat description.

Comment: I have updated the question, and answered it according to the new feat description.

Answer (score 3):

**With the Updated feat Description:**

> **Battle Song Expertise**
>   You gain a +1 feat bonus to attack rolls you make with *any weapon with which you are proficient* and with a wand or another item designated as a bard implement. This bonus increases to +2 at 11th level and +3 at 21st level.
>   You also gain a +1 feat bonus to the number of squares that you can pull, push, or slide creatures with your bard attacks and bard paragon path attacks.

The **Battle Song Expertise** feat now applies to all weapons and implements a Bard will ever use, including weapons that are being used as implements, as when using the **Arcane Implement Proficiency** feat.

Comment: For completeness, can you cite the source of the updated description in your answer?

Comment: I'd edited the question to have the updated feat description. Did the edit not go through? I'll edit it again, then put the description here again.

Comment: The question just needs peer review now.

Comment: Since that would change the question the edit has been rejected. It's enough to cite the updated text in your answer.

Comment: OK thanks, wasn't sure what to do with outdated questions. I'll know how to do it next time.